# Pass image from photoOutput(didFinishProcessingPhoto) in PhotoCaptureDelegate.swift to my ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

In PhotoCaptureDelegate.swift, I have this function:

```
/// - Tag: DidFinishProcessingPhoto
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    photoProcessingHandler(false)

    print("photo output called")

    if let error = error {
        print("Error capturing photo: \(error)")
    } else {
        photoData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()    
    }
}
```

I want the photoData as a static preview image in my UIView in my ViewController after I took a photo. I tried to pass the photoData to a variable in my ViewController or call a function and set it, but the UIElements are nil when I call it from PhotoCaptureDelegate.swift.

**How can I use the photoData as a preview image, when the didFinishProcessingPhoto function is called in a delegate?**

In case it is relevant, this is how I take a photo:

```
@IBAction func buttonTakePhotoTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let videoPreviewLayerOrientation = viewPreview.videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation

    sessionQueue.async {
        if let photoOutputConnection = self.photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
            photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = videoPreviewLayerOrientation!
        }

        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

        if self.videoDeviceInput.device.isFlashAvailable {
            photoSettings.flashMode = .auto
        }

        photoSettings.photoQualityPrioritization = self.photoQualityPrioritizationMode

        let photoCaptureProcessor = PhotoCaptureProcessor(with: photoSettings, willCapturePhotoAnimation: {
            // Flash the screen to signal that AVCam took a photo.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.viewPreview.videoPreviewLayer.opacity = 0
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                    self.viewPreview.videoPreviewLayer.opacity = 1
                }
            }
        }, livePhotoCaptureHandler: { capturing in
            self.sessionQueue.async {
            }
        }, completionHandler: { photoCaptureProcessor in
            // When the capture is complete, remove a reference to the photo capture delegate so it can be deallocated.
            self.sessionQueue.async {
                self.inProgressPhotoCaptureDelegates[photoCaptureProcessor.requestedPhotoSettings.uniqueID] = nil
            }
        }, photoProcessingHandler: { animate in
            }
        )

        // The photo output holds a weak reference to the photo capture delegate and stores it in an array to maintain a strong reference.
        self.inProgressPhotoCaptureDelegates[photoCaptureProcessor.requestedPhotoSettings.uniqueID] = photoCaptureProcessor
        self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: photoCaptureProcessor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the `PhotoCaptureProcessor` with several callback blocks that get called at different stages of the capture process. In the `completionHandler` you should be able to access the captured photo from the `photoCaptureProcessor`. Something like this:

```
let photoCaptureProcessor = PhotoCaptureProcessor(with: photoSettings, willCapturePhotoAnimation: {
    // ...
}, livePhotoCaptureHandler: { capturing in
    // ...
}, completionHandler: { photoCaptureProcessor in
    let capturedImage = UIImage(data: photoCaptureProcessor.photoData)
    // be sure to perform UI changes in main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // assuming the image view is named like that...
        self.imageView.image = capturedImage
    }

    // ...
}, photoProcessingHandler: { animate in
    // ...
})
```